# Specific information from json string

Tags: java, json, twitter

I've been playing around with tweets in Eclipse for a while, which are presented as a json string.

To this end, I've created an object called Tweet (original, huh?) which takes certain information from the json string, and stores it in the Tweet object. Nothing fancy.

My Tweet class looks as follows:

```
public class Tweet implements TwitterMelding {

public Tweet() {
}

String created_at;
String id;
String text;
String user;

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}
}
```

Now, simple as it may look, there is one of those that doesn't work.

Specifically *String user*. What it's suppose to do, is store user ID of the person who posted the tweet.

The following is the tweet as obtained from Twitter in all it's horrible length:

```
{"created_at":"Sat Feb 08 15:37:37 +0000 2014","id":432176397474623489,"id_str":"432176397474623489","text":"Skal begynne \u00e5 selge vekter.. Eneste m\u00e5ten det konstant kommer penger i lommen","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":366301747,"id_str":"366301747","name":"skinny-pete","screen_name":"JFarsund","location":"bj\u00f8rge","url":null,"description":"j\u00f8rgen er en tynn gutt med pack.. Men det teller vel ikke? Det gj\u00f8r vel ikke bio heller","protected":false,"followers_count":427,"friends_count":291,"listed_count":2,"created_at":"Thu Sep 01 23:03:49 +0000 2011","favourites_count":5103,"utc_offset":3600,"time_zone":"Copenhagen","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":8827,"lang":"no","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000089578611\/6840970475350d63190eb05d3d7e47ec.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000089578611\/6840970475350d63190eb05d3d7e47ec.png","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/431961396528414720\/EwkxQBkW_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/431961396528414720\/EwkxQBkW_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/366301747\/1391822743","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[60.33700829,5.24626808]},"coordinates":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[5.24626808,60.33700829]},"place":{"id":"2260fcb4a77f2bad","url":"https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1.1\/geo\/id\/2260fcb4a77f2bad.json","place_type":"city","name":"Bergen","full_name":"Bergen, Hordaland","country_code":"NO","country":"Norge","contained_within":[],"bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.1602697,60.1848543],[5.1602697,60.5335445],[5.6866852,60.5335445],[5.6866852,60.1848543]]]},"attributes":{}},"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"no"}
```

It really is a long eye-sore.

I've added a few "..." to the next one, to make it slightly more readable, only showing the value I'm interested in:

```
{…,"user":{"id":366301747,"id_str":"366301747","name":"skinny-pete","screen_name":"JFarsund","location":"bj\u00f8rge","url":null,"description":"j\u00f8rgen er en tynn gutt med pack.. Men det teller vel ikke? Det gj\u00f8r vel ikke bio heller","protected":false,"followers_count":427,"friends_count":291,"listed_count":2,"created_at":"Thu Sep 01 23:03:49 +0000 2011","favourites_count":5103,"utc_offset":3600,"time_zone":"Copenhagen","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":8827,"lang":"no","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000089578611\/6840970475350d63190eb05d3d7e47ec.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000089578611\/6840970475350d63190eb05d3d7e47ec.png","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/431961396528414720\/EwkxQBkW_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/431961396528414720\/EwkxQBkW_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/366301747\/1391822743","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null}, …}
```

Right, still with me?

As I mentioned above, what I want is the users ID, which I want assigned to the variable "user" in the Tweet object.

```
{…,"user":{"id":366301747,"id_str":"366301747",… }…}
```

All I want is to assign the number **366301747**, to the variable "user" in my Tweet object.

But for the life of me, I cannot seem to.

To make sure the Tweet object gets the info it wants and not the info it doesn't, I am using a Jackson object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

So my question.

How do I tell Tweet to take the **366301747** number from my json string and assign it to the variable "user"?

I'd prefer it doable with Jackson alone, and not having to import more JARs than necessary.

Please forgive the wall of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be pretty straightforward with [`Gson`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.

Since, you've already done the hard work of creating the pojo, by looking at your `json` you can validate that `User` is a valid `json` object and not a `String` value.

Hence, let's modify your pojo's (`Tweet`) `user` attribute a little with:

```
User user;

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

Where `User` custom class is:

```
public class User {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Now just call the your Gson method to convert your object from the `json` (I stored the `json` to a file and read it through a `BufferedReader`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "json.txt"));

        Tweet tweetObj = gson.fromJson(br, Tweet.class);
        System.out.println(tweetObj.getUser().getId());
    }
```

Output:

```
366301747
```

**EDIT: Based on the comments, solution using jackson - 2 options**

1. Keep newly created `User` class, the ObjectMapper code remains exactly the same and `System.out.println(tweet.getUser().getId())` gets you the userid.
2. If `User` class is not to be used, change your `Tweet` to look like this:

Code:

```
public class Tweet {

    String created_at;
    String id;
    String text;
    Map<String, String> user;

    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Map<String, String> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

And print the `userid` in the calling method as:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

Tweet tweet = mapper.readValue(br, Tweet.class);

System.out.println(tweet.getUser().get("id"));
```

Gets you:

```
366301747
```

Comment: I see what you mean, which looks like an acceptable idea. But is there any way I can do it without the class User? I mean, can I get the user ID straight from my Tweet object? Would this by any chance work with Jackson? I ask forgiveness if I'm being difficult.

Comment: You sir, deserve more than ONE beer. I am truly thankful, as I sat hours not getting this. It works now. You made my entire day!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `setUser` method to take a `Map` and set `user.id` manually:

```
public void setUser(Map<String, Object> props) {
    user = props.get("id").toString();
}
```

Comment: I'm a little new to Map, so would you care to explain how I would utilize the setUser method with the json string above? What argument would I use for this method in my scenario? Forgive the newbie-question.

Comment: Basically when you have `setUser(Map props)` method then `props` will be a map `{"id":366301747,"id_str":"366301747","name":"skinny-pete", ...` . You then can extract json `id` field and assign it to `this.user`. `user = props.get("id").toString()` does exactly that. And since you're using Jackson you don't need to pass an argument to `setUser` yourself. Jackson will call the `setUser` method behind the scenes when you do `mapper.readValue(...)`